# Unable to upload picture to facebook From android app with different user than me

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an android app with facebook sdk api integration that allow user to login to facebook and share picture. I've tested my android app by log in with my facebook account (my account is the owner of facebook app) and everithing work well. But if i log in with another account (that is not owner of Facebook app) i'm not able to upload picture. I receive this error;

12-04 13:35:33.484: I/FACEBOOK(20673): {HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) Permissions error}

i update picture in this way:

```
final ProgressDialog spinner = new ProgressDialog(this);

    // Part 1: create callback to get URL of uploaded photo
    Request.Callback uploadPhotoRequestCallback = new Request.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            String alert_title = "";
            String alert_message = "";

            if (response.getError() != null) {
                Log.i("FACEBOOK", response.getError().toString());
                alert_title = FullPics.this.getString(R.string.alert_error);
                alert_message = FullPics.this
                        .getString(R.string.publish_pic_fail);

            } else {

                Object graphResponse = response.getGraphObject()
                        .getProperty("id");
                if (graphResponse == null
                        || !(graphResponse instanceof String)
                        || TextUtils.isEmpty((String) graphResponse)) { 
                    Log.d("FULL", "failed photo upload/no response");
                    alert_title = FullPics.this
                            .getString(R.string.alert_error);
                    alert_message = FullPics.this
                            .getString(R.string.publish_pic_fail);
                } else {

                    alert_title = FullPics.this
                            .getString(R.string.alert_success);
                    alert_message = FullPics.this
                            .getString(R.string.publish_pic_success);
                } 
            } 
            spinner.dismiss();
            showMessage(alert_title, alert_message);
        }
    };

    File image_file = fragmentAdapter.getCurrentImageFile(pager
            .getCurrentItem());
    Request request;
    try {

        spinner.setMessage(getString(R.string.publish_pic_in_progress));
        spinner.setCancelable(false);
        spinner.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        spinner.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        spinner.show();
        request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(
                Session.openActiveSession(this, false, null), image_file,
                uploadPhotoRequestCallback);
        request.executeAsync();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

what's wrong? maybe i need to set something on Facebook developer site inside my app?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your facebook app is private to you only. If you observe your app on facebook there will be little green circle which will be shown as disabled if your api is private.

It should public and filled with green color. Then only other user can use this app.

Visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/bestpractice/managing-development-cycle?locale=en_GB for more info

Answer (score 0):

according to new facebook sdk, you need to submit your app for review if you are publishing anything.
after facebook approval you can upload picture by using any login.
you can check this link for review process

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/

https://github.com/sauce/guide/wiki/Facebook's-approval-process

Comment: but i can add some user as tester for use app?

Comment: yes you can, but that user must be in your friend list